# Eclipse content assist and completion

Tags: xml, eclipse, content-assist

When typing xml in eclipse, content assist will add the closing tag of my xml. 
I type  eclipse adds . As soon as I type a character in the body between the opening and ending tag, eclipse instantly puts an outline around the last character of the closing tag.

It seems obvious that after you've completed typing the body, there ought to be a way to advance the cursor to that position at the end of the tag. I can't figure out how to do it.

In java it would be tab, but that doesn't work, nor does ctrl-tab. Does anyone know what magic key combo advances the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit `alt+shift+up` as many time as required to expand selection to include end tag then `right` to clear the selection and the cursor is left just after end tag!!

Answer (score 1):

There is none (aside from @nanda's point about the `End` button).  The Eclipse XML editor could use some of that kind of stuff.  I myself would like the expand-selection commands (usually mapped to Alt-Shift-UpArrow and Alt-Shift-DownArrow) to handle attribute selection and the like, and poked into the code a bit.

If anyone wants to collaborate with me, I'll set up a project on Eclipse Labs to do it.

Answer (score -1):

How about the most obvious thing? Using `End` button you will go to the end of the line